# Should I use UIIntegers when not needed

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a large NSMutableArray of `int`s, the value of which will never exceed 10 bits. Is there a good reason to use NSInteger instead? I would prefer using the smallest amounts of bits possible.

Comment: You can't hold primitives in an NSArray, so the number of bits isn't really an issue here.

Comment: As an NSArray stores pointers, you _could_ treat your ints as pointers, store them and retrieve them. Only problem is: NSArray retains its values, which will probably crash your app. Also, if you're trying to be bit-level efficient, do not use high level languages. You could, for example, fall back to C, then create your mutable array of integers yourself :)